# limejs fails to compile

Tags: javascript, html, compilation, limejs

I have made an file 'test' using the create command, so I have two files. A html and a few other js files. now I want to compile all the js files so I use this line in the commandprompt:
C:\limejs\bin>lime.py build test -o test/compiled.js

I'm using windows 8

but the only thing I receive is this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\limejs\closure\closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 265, in <mo
dule>
    main()
  File "C:\limejs\closure\closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 234, in mai
n
    deps = [base] + tree.GetDependencies(input_namespaces)
  File "C:\limejs\closure\closure\bin\build\depstree.py", line 80, in GetDepende
ncies
    namespace, [], self._provides_map, []):
  File "C:\limejs\closure\closure\bin\build\depstree.py", line 118, in _ResolveD
ependencies
    raise NamespaceNotFoundError(required_namespace)
depstree.NamespaceNotFoundError: Namespace "test" never provided.
```

I thought it might is because I can't use -o in windows command prompt but I really don't know what causes this error.

now i have done that I receive this error:

```
C:\limejs\closure\closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Scanning paths...
C:\limejs\closure\closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: 1464 sources scanned.
C:\limejs\closure\closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Building dependency tree.
.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\limejs\closure\closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 265, in <mo
dule>
    main()
  File "C:\limejs\closure\closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py", line 254, in mai
n
    compiler_flags=options.compiler_flags)
  File "C:\limejs\closure\closure\bin\build\jscompiler.py", line 125, in Compile

    java_version = _ParseJavaVersion(_GetJavaVersionString())
  File "C:\limejs\closure\closure\bin\build\jscompiler.py", line 37, in _GetJava
VersionString
    return subprocess.check_output(['java', '-version'], stderr=subprocess.STDOU
T)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-version']' returned non-zero
exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That error happens when the Google Closures Compiler can't find your file. Make sure in "test.js" (or whichever file has your javascript entry point) has the line:

```
goog.provide("test")
```

Check Limejs guide:
http://www.limejs.com/0-getting-started

Comment: now i have done that I receive this error:see edited

Comment: Google Closures Compiler is actually a Java program. Make sure you have Java installed. Look at this: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app